# Biblatex style for author only and numbered when not unique

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

How do I get a biblatex style which only displays the author, i.e. *Hans*, and in case there are several publications by the same author, numbers them like *Hans1* and *Hans2* ?

Comment: What if you have multiple authors?

Comment: It should print [Hans,Paul] then.

Comment: With a comma and no space? Is there a maximum number of authors?

Comment: A space would be good, maximum number of authors is okay (lets say 2 or 3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `alphabetic` style that should be as easy as

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[pcompound=true,namessep={,}]{labelname}
  }
}
```

The argument to `namessep` gives the separator between names of multiple authors/editors, I used a comma without space following your comment.

With

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{#1}
```

we get "1", "2", ... for disambiguation instead of the standard "a", "b", ...

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[pcompound=true,namessep={,}]{labelname}
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{#1}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]