# Alphabetic citation label with name only

Tags: biblatex

I use `biblatex` and I want to have a citation style with no date but initials of the authors such as "[BDM]" for three authors and "[Kr]" for one author.

In this case if there are more than one citation of the same author(s) then I want the citation style to continue by 1,2,3; such as "[AL1],[AL2]" or "[Br1],[Br2]"

Is it possible to make such changes in `biblatex`? My current settings are

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, giveninits=true,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
```

Comment: This should be possible. But it is easier if you have a base to start from. Do you have a style that you like except for the labels, maybe `alpha.bst` or something else?

Comment: so far I used only bibtex. I did not form or use and bst

Comment: What did you write in `\bibliographystyle` and which additional packages did you load (`cite`, `natbib`, `jurabib`, `apacite`, ...)?

Comment: I have \usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, giveninits=true,sorting=nyt]{biblatex} and \addbibresource{sample.bib} which I included references.

Comment: Then you are using `biblatex`. That is differently entirely. These kinds of misunderstandings and confusions are a reason why so often we ask for a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) when you post a question.

Comment: Related, but not real duplicates https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415709/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/382859/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320560/35864, though the combination of these answer would probably have solved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `biblatex` and Biber you can control the format of the alphabetic labels with `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`. The additional disambiguation is normally a letter, but it can be turned into a number easily.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{#1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum,companion,aksin,cotton,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The citations read "SR; Wo; Nu; GMS; Ak+; Co+; Kn1; Kn2"]